# Core Data, how to remove one element from relationship's collection (NSSet)

Tags: swift, core-data, relationship

I have a many to many Core Data Model as below, Playlist and Songs.

[image]

I could add song to Playlist's relationship (song) successfully, for an instance, playlist1(song1) -> after added, playlist(song1, song2). As below code showed, to use addToSong(song) method, which is auto-generated by CoreData and use to add object into relationship.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // fetch selected playlist first
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Playlist>(entityName: "Playlist")

        let currentCell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
        let cellText = currentCell?.textLabel?.text
        print("cell text", cellText ?? "No Playlist Name")

        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name = '\(cellText!)' ", "")
        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

        let song = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Song", into: context) as! Song
        song.songName = playingSong?.songName
        song.artistName = playingSong?.artistName
        song.albumName = playingSong?.albumName
        song.fileURL = playingSong?.url
        print("song name", playingSong?.songName ?? "no songName")

        do {
            let selectedPlaylists = try self.context.fetch(fetchRequest)
            for item in selectedPlaylists {
                item.addToSong(song)

            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not delete. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }


        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

        // show short alert message to user
        showAlert(userMessage: "Song added")
    }
```

But when I try to remove some songs from Playlist's relationship, to use removeFromSong(song), it is not working. In my case, what I want to do is that, e.g. before, playlist1(song1, song2, song3) and after removeFromSong(xx), playlist1(song2, song3). I do search the network, but not find how to locate the specific object to remove from relationship, any help could be appreciated!

/ / / in below code, I create a new Song object and assign it two attributes as songName and artistName, then use removeFromSong() to remove this new created song from playlist's relationship, but I don't know if this way could locate the correct song saved in relationship.

```
func deleteSong(indexPath: IndexPath) {

        // remove record from Playlist entity of DB
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Playlist>(entityName: "Playlist")

        let currentCell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
        // let cellText = currentCell?.textLabel?.text
        let cellText = navigationItem.title

        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name = '\(cellText!)' ", "")
        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

        let song = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Song", into: context) as! Song
        song.songName = currentCell?.textLabel?.text
        song.artistName = currentCell?.detailTextLabel?.text

        do {
            let selectedPlaylists = try self.context.fetch(fetchRequest)
            for item in selectedPlaylists {
                // delete selected song in current playlist
                item.removeFromSong(song)

                // item.objectIDs(forRelationshipNamed: <#T##String#>)
                // save the changes after deleting
                try context.save()
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not delete. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }

        // remove data from tableView
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.automatic)

        //refresh tableView
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

/ / / as vadian's comment, change my code as below.

Changes:

1. update relationship's name as songs and playlists.
2. remove code pattern of `insertNewObject`, now fetch/find the selected song from Sony entity first. Then remove that song `removeFromSong(song)`from playlist.
3. remove `reloadData`, which is not needed to appear after `deleteRow`.

**Question:** Now I could remove the selected from the tableView via swiping to delete, but if I force close the App or navi to other view and back, the delete item is backed. So the deletion is not effected in Core Data model. As I use below code like adding songs, which is worked fine, so where is the issue for deletion, any hint is appropriated.

```
do {
            let selectedPlaylists = try self.context.fetch(fetchRequest)
            for item in selectedPlaylists {
                // delete selected song in current playlist
                print("Ready to remove!!!!!")
                item.removeFromSongs(selectedSong[0])

                // save the changes after deleting
                try self.context.save()
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not delete. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
```

/ / / the full code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ShowPlaylistDetailsViewController: UITableViewController {


    var song: SongData?
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    var playlistObjects = [Playlist]()
    var songObjects = [Song]()
    var playlistName = ""
    var selectedSong = [Song]()
    // var rowCount: Int?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        // set navigation controller's title
        navigationItem.title = playlistName

        // print("playlist name", playlistName)

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Playlist>(entityName: "Playlist")
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name = '\(playlistName)' ", "")
        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

        do {
            playlistObjects = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        } catch {
            fatalError("Can not query: \(error)")
        }

        songObjects = playlistObjects[0].songs?.allObjects as! [Song]

        // refresh table data.
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // print("songs count", songsCount!)
        return songObjects.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "showPlaylistDetails", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = songObjects[indexPath.row].songName
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = songObjects[indexPath.row].artistName
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "icons8-music-50")
        cell.imageView?.layer.cornerRadius = 0.8

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {

            let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Delete", handler: { (action, view, completion) in
                self.deleteSong(indexPath: indexPath)
            })

            // action.image = UIImage(named: "My Image")
            deleteAction.backgroundColor = .red
            let swipeActions = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction])
            swipeActions.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = false
            return swipeActions
        }

    func deleteSong(indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // find current selected cell
        let currentCell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)

        // find the deleted song
        let fetchRequestForSong = NSFetchRequest<Song>(entityName: "Song")
        let ssName = currentCell?.textLabel?.text
        print("ssName", ssName ?? "Song name retrieve failed")
        let predicateForSong = NSPredicate(format: "songName = '\(ssName ?? "Song name retrieve failed")' ", "")
        fetchRequestForSong.predicate = predicateForSong
        do {
            selectedSong = try self.context.fetch(fetchRequestForSong)
            // print("songName", selectedSong.first?.songName)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not delete. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }

        // find current selected playlist
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Playlist>(entityName: "Playlist")
        let cellText = navigationItem.title
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name = '\(cellText!)' ", "")
        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

        do {
            let selectedPlaylists = try self.context.fetch(fetchRequest)
            for item in selectedPlaylists {
                // delete selected song in current playlist
                print("Ready to remove!!!!!")
                item.removeFromSongs(selectedSong[0])

                // save the changes after deleting
                try self.context.save()
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not delete. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }

        // remove song from dataSource array
        songObjects.remove(at: indexPath.row)

        // remove data from tableView
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.automatic)
    }

    @IBAction func naviBack(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated:true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is very confusing. First of all you should name to-many relationships in plural form:  `songs` and `playlists`. You are inserting a new song in the `deleteSong`. This cannot work. You have to fetch the song for given name and artist and remove it from the playlist(s) you want. And **never ever** get static data from the cell, get it from the data model. And never call `reloadData` right after `deleteRows`.

Comment: @vadian, I update my code as your advice, it is really wrong for the insert part...my brain is messy at that time. Well, there is still some issues like the ```removeFromSong()``` is not really remove that song from playlist's relationship, could you help?

Comment: I'm still confused. Why do you fetch the song although you can get it from the `songObjects` array with the given index (path)? And the predicate format string looks pretty weird. Why not standard `NSPredicate(format: "name == %@", cellText)` syntax? And it's very bad practice to execute code after a `do catch` block as if an error never occurs. I don't know what `removeFromSongs` does but it seems that it does remove the song from the relationship. And once again, do **not** get any data from a cell label, get it from the item in `songObjects`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my comments this is cleaned up version of the delete method which is supposed to work if `removeFromSongs` does remove the song from the relationship

```
func deleteSong(at indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // get current selected song
    let currentSong = songObjects[indexPath.row]

    // find current selected playlist
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Playlist>(entityName: "Playlist")
    let cellText = navigationItem.title
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name == %@", cellText!)
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
    fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1

    do {
        if let selectedPlaylist = try self.context.fetch(fetchRequest).first {    
            print("Ready to remove!!!!!")
            selectedPlaylist.removeFromSongs(currentSong)

            // save the changes after deleting
            try self.context.save()

            // remove song from dataSource array
            songObjects.remove(at: indexPath.row)

            // remove data from tableView
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        }
    } catch {
        print("Could not delete.", error)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, vadian. I change my code as like yours, now the deletion take the effect on Core Data model. And yes, I forget to add the ```if``` before ```let, try``` when using ```do catch```, and I change other format issue like ```NSPredicate```, well your answer really help me that I think there could has many format issues like this in my project:)